# My Auto Log in using Firebase on android studio is not working

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm developing the log in feature for an Android app using firebase. What i want is that when the user log in and the exit the apps without log out, and then re open the apps, they will be automatically log in and go to HomeFragment(BottomNavigationBar). But on this code, what happen is that when i first install the apps, it just automatically open the HomeFragment(BottomNavigationBar) .

This is the first activity when the user open the apps:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Delay for 2 seconds
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
//              CHECKING IS THERE USER OR NOT
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    // User is signed in (getCurrentUser() will be null if not signed in)
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BottomNavigationBar.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    //User is not logged in, go to login page
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
        hideNavigationBar();
    }
```

This is an additional information where the error happen right when i implemented this code for google log in its only just a possibility tho

LoginActivity:

```
// After successful login, check if this is the user's first time logging in
boolean isNewUser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
if (isNewUser) {
    // Redirect to Home Page if new user
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginPage.this, PreferencePage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} else {
    // Redirect to Preference Page if existing user
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginPage.this, BottomNavigationBar.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

i've tried reversed it , and comment the cause and everything else, chat gpt and stuff im so confuse and stuck with this bug, what i want to happen is simple, because it has worked before, when i use the sharedpreference instead the boolean, the result when i change into a boolean is that

Comment: You might want to try if an auth state listener picks up the user, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, since you're still using Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).